# How can I access the profiles/show.html.erb in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, many-to-many

I´m using Devise, and after signing up, I want my users to access the `profiles/show.html.erb`

I have an `registrations_controller.rb` and in there I have this piece of code

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_user_profile_path(current_user) 
end
```

It directs the user to `profiles/new.html.erb` but I want the user to go to `profiles/show.html.erb`

the `rake routes`shows this paths:

```
new_user_profile  GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                  GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
```

how would I modify this chunk of code to direct to the `profiles/show.html.erb`?

I'm to unexperienced to figure this out by my self, any help would be greate

this is my `routes.rb`file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
 resources :users do
 resource :profile
end


root 'pages#index'

end
```

** Edit**

`the rake routes output`

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
       cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 registrations#new
       edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)                         registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                         registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                         registrations#destroy
        user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)        profiles#create
       new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)    profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format)   profiles#edit
                     GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)        profiles#show
                     PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)        profiles#update
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)        profiles#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)        profiles#destroy
               users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
                     POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
                     PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
                     GET    /%20/users/:user_id/profile(.:format)%20 profiles#show
                root GET    /                                        pages#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, check your github. 
 Spelling of your resource is wrong
 It should be `resources :profile` not `resource :profile`
that is why it was not showing you the paths to the profile resources through `rake routes` command. 
I used the `profile_path(current_user)` in the show action at profile_controller.rb file

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you need to create

```
def show 

end
```

You can also try replacing your code in registration controller with.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    show_user_profile_path(current_user) 
end
```

Comment: sorry it gives me this error `undefined method 'show_user_profile_path' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007fe84571efc8>`

Comment: after including the
    def show
    end
may I see your rake routes output?

Comment: yes there is `def show` in my users_controller.rb, registrations_controller.rb and profiles_controller.rb

Comment: try to include this in your route.rb file 
get ' /users/:user_id/profile(.:format) ', to: 'profiles#show'
You need to understanding how routing works. Read about this here -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: remove 'do' in front of this ' resources :users do' and then rerun rake routes. 
I also i noticed an error with your profile show action. 
 GET    /%20/users/:user_id/profile(.:format)%20 profiles#show
this is not a correct out put. 
So just remove do and rerun rake routes, it should give you valid paths afterwards.

Comment: If I move the do rails throws back this error on sign up `undefined method 'show_user_profile_path' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007fe8456c1d50>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123030/discussion-between-mayorsanmayor-and-dadi-hall).

Answer (score 1):

remove 'do' from resources :users do in routes.rb file.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) 
  user_path(current_user) 
end
```

`rake routes` shows `user GET /users/:id(.:format) users#show`

Comment: Yeah this is working for the user page, but I wan't to go to the profiles/show.html.erb.... please see the chat

Answer (score 1):

routes.rb

```
get 'profiles/show', to: 'profiles/show', as: :profile
```

profiles_controller.rb

```
def show
 unless params[:user_id] @user = User.find(current_user.id)
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

and then

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) 
  profile_path
end
```